# countdown clock in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a test engine web application. Users will be give some amount of time to answer questions. I want to create a countdown clock after which the test is finished. I'm using javascript right now but facing problems of refresh and back button in the browser. 
Following is the javascript:

```
<script>
function countDown (count) {

  if (count > 0) {
      var hours = Math.floor(count/3600)
      var minutes =  Math.floor(count/60) - (hours*60)
      var seconds = count - (minutes * 60) - (hours*3600)

   var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");

      d.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  else
   document.location = "test_finished.html";
}
countDown(<%=@totaltime%>);
</script>
```

How can i disable the refresh and back button or some other workaround??

Comment: You can't reliably disable either the back button or refresh. If the user does either, just start the test again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enforce such things using JavaScript.

One way would be to have records in the database which hold the test start date time in it, once a user starts a test the start time is set, upon loading the initial timer value is calculated using it, so you can have back and refresh working fine and the countdown timer always being accurate.

Comment: Rather than use a database, which would require communication with the rails backend, you could write the start time into the browser session.  However, this might be easy to spoof, so the db approach is probably better.  I would do as Tomas says, with an ajax call to check the remaining time every ten seconds, which gets the remaining time as a return, and updates the clock (which still continues to count down in the normal way using js), and submits the form or whatever if the time has ran out.